# Необходимо с помощью js изменить ссылку

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо поменять ссылку "sates0.html" на "index.html"

Comment: Это русское сообщество StackOverflow! Переведите пожалуйста ваш вопрос на русский язык.

Answer (score 4):

```
document.querySelector('a').setAttribute('href', 'index.html');
```

Доки [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)